# How does "kubectl apply" verify change in docker image?

Tags: github, kubernetes, kubectl

We are performing rolling updates for change in docker image.

Deployment tool(harness) runs `kubectl apply` command for every  change in docker image.

---

Rolling updates are by default i.e., we do not need to provide below `strategy` in the YAML:

```
strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 1
    maxUnavailable: 1  # this will ensure zero downtime
```

---

With regards to change in docker image, is it the name of docker image that decides `kubectl apply` to perform rolling update? Because the docker image we have is, tagged as `image-name:latest`

Comment: besides name, there is also hash.

Comment: @LeiYang you mean, `image-name:{github-sha}`

Comment: can you also paste a sample file(such as deployment yaml) which you apply?

Comment: `kubectl apply` does not perform rolling updates: it just updates objects in the API server. Then various controllers act correspondingly. If nothing has changed in the manifest - nothing would be updated.

Comment: @zerkms After `kubectl apply`, upon change docker image,  does old version pods get shutdown without waiting for active connections(browser to Pods) to get closed?

Comment: @overexchange the container is sent a SIGTERM signal, it's up to the application on how it handles it.

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl apply` (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply)) only looks for changes in the Kubernetes resource specifications (the YAML) and not inside Docker images. So, if you change your Docker image and publish it with the same name and tag (i.e. your Kubernetes resource YAML doesn't change), then `kubectl apply` alone won't do anything.

The automatic redeployment of resources when the Docker image changes is probably implemented as a feature of Harness on top of `kubectl apply`.

Comment: Are you saying that, old version Pod will be abruptly shutdown and new version pods will be started(with updated docker image name)?

Comment: Not abruptly, but according to the rolling update strategy defined in your Deployment. I guess that Harness internally updates the name of the Docker image when it changes and then does a `kubectl apply`. So the normal update logic applies as defined in your Deployment. You can do `kubectl get pods -o yaml` on the Pods managed by Harness to see what image name they use.